# Finite soluble group is $\pi$-separable for every $\pi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

> **Definition** *A finite group $G$ is $\pi$-separable if has a series (supposed to be subnormal) where each factor is either a $\pi$-group of $\pi'$-group.*

$\pi$ is a set of prime numbers and $\pi'$ is a set os prime numbers that are not in $\pi$.

This definitions comes from the Robinson's book "A Course in the Theory of Groups".

He says that a finite soluble group is $\pi$-separable for **every** $\pi$. How can I see it? Robinson says to refine the derived series inserting the $\pi$-component of each factor. Maybe this is a stupid question, but I cannot follow this explanation.

Comment: A finite abelian group is the product of its Sylow-$p$-subgroups.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I know that we can take a $\pi$-component of each factor because it is abelian, but I cannot see how the refinement will satisfied the conditions, or in which places we must insert these $\pi$-components

Comment: Take a composition series for a finite soluble group.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Nice! I can see why the claim is true using the composition series. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, I sill would like to understand the Robinson's idea.

Comment: @Greg Refine the derived series to a composition series. That's all he wants. You can refine the derived series so that at each stage the abelian group is split into the $\pi$- and $\pi'$-parts, or just go all the way down to $p$-groups.